# Autostart Unpriviledged LXC Containers

Tags: autostart, lxc

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and have installed LXC normally. I've followed the [official LXC documentation](https://www.stgraber.org/2014/01/17/lxc-1-0-unprivileged-containers/) to set up unprivileged containers under a non-root user.

These don't seem to support LXC's autostart functionality. Has anyone worked around this?

Comment: Your question doesn't really give all that much information. I suggest you [edit] it to include what you tried, why it didn't work, any research you did and what exactly you were hoping for/expecting.

Comment: That is much better, thank you. We still need a few more details however. A link to the installation docs would be nice. When you say "doesn't seem to support..." how did you reach that conclusion?

Comment: @Seth I'll add in a link to the docs to set up non-privileged users. As for how I know it doesn't work out of the box. The init stuff just isn't written to be aware of containers for anyone other than root any more - it used to be more manual requiring creation of symlinks per machine which would better support this use case. However back then unprivileged containers weren't well supported. I gleaned this from the LXC mailing list archives. I was just hoping someone might have already encountered this problem and patched the init stuff to be more compatible

Answer (score 0):

I've written a small [script](https://gist.github.com/tarruda/2aea9107f04d8b8d8dbf) to work around the issue, just follow the commented instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Try put in /etc/rc.local:

/bin/su -c /usr/bin/lxc-autostart *USER*

Comment: Since `rc.local` is run as `root`, the `su -c` is not needed.